# reactjs expressjs how to setup proxy? proxy doesn't work with localhost:3000, but works with localhost:3000/test

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

Trying to work with reactjs (`create-react-app`) and now including `expressjs`. What I've done is

1. move my `folder/*` to `folder/client/*` (deleting `node_modules`)
2. cd `folder/client/` and `npm install` to recreate the `node_modules`
   *it works as before, the app renders well
3. `cd folder` and `npm init`
4. `npm install express --save`
5. write the `folder/server.js`
6. add the proxy settings in `/folder/client/package.json`
7. `npm run start` in `/folder` and in `/folder/client`

Then, I go to `localhost:3000` and I get the reactjs app, without express anywhere. Then I go to `localhost:8080` and I get the express result, which is indeed the same page as before but without being executed by react (nothing wrong here, I assume)

And then I go to `localhost:3000/test` and it gets proxied to express, where I see in the terminal the console.log of `server.js`

So I cannot proxy `localhost:3000`, but I can `localhost:3000/whatever`. **What is wrong?**

**server.js**

```
    const express = require('express');
    const path = require('path'); // haven't installed, should I?
    const app = express();
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build'))); // of no use here

    app.get('/ping', function (req, res) { // this one works
     return res.send('pong');
    });

//    app.get('', function (req, res) { // doesn't work
//    app.get('*', function (req, res) { // doesn't work
//    app.get('.', function (req, res) { // doesn't work
//    app.get('.*', function (req, res) { // doesn't work
//    app.get('./', function (req, res) { // doesn't work
    app.get('./*', function (req, res) { // doesn't work
      console.log('hey') // never seen
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/src', 'index.html'));
    });

    app.get('/test', function (req, res) { // this one works
      console.log('hey2') // I do see this when calling localhost:3000/test
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/src', 'index.html'));
    });

    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

**package.json (/)**

```
{
  "name": "ouyea",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app).",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://xxxx"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://xxxx"
  },
  "homepage": "https://xxxx",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4"
  }
}
```

**package.json (/client)**

```
    {
      "name": "client",
      "version": "0.1.1",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "googleapis": "^33.0.0",
        "papaparse": "4.6.0",
        "react": "^16.4.2",
        "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
        "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
        "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.0",
        "semantic-ui-react": "^0.82.5"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "proxy": {
        "": { // I know comments don't work, but I put them here for clarity, none of them worked
//        "*": {
//        ".": {
//        "/": {
          "target": "http://localhost:8080"
        },
        "/test": {
          "target": "http://localhost:8080"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. `localhost:3000` is your development react app (presumably running hot module reload)? The point is that you use the 8080 proxy to hit endpoints in your express app like `localhost:3000/api` to fetch data.

Comment: ahhh ... I see ... so express is not managing the app, is only a server to manage services that need to be in the back-end. Am I saying this correctly? then who is managing the app?

Comment: Yes, for your purposes. There are apps that are React pages rendered on the server using Express/Koa etc, and which use React client-side (universal/isomorphic apps) but that's not what you're doing here.

Comment: Could you write the same as an answer so that I can close this? otherwise I can discard the question but ... well, it may sound silly but I was stuck here :_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the express server is to simply a) render the base HTML page from your `dist` folder, and b) supply data from endpoints that you set up as routes in Express which can be accessed by your React client application. There are apps (universal) that can render React pages from Express but that's not what you're doing here with `create-react-app`.